# Как извлечь обложку из MP3-файла на Python?

Tags: python

Я гуглил и видел несколько вариантов с использованием модуля **mutagen**. Но у меня они не работают. При этом об ошибках терминал в VS Code не сообщает, все выглядит так, как будто код завершается успешно.
Вот один из способов:

```
import mutagen.mp3
import logging

local_file = 'C:\\Users\\101ap\\Desktop\\music\\13.Numb.mp3'
covers_dir = 'C:\\Users\\101ap\\Desktop\\Player\\Covers'
cover_name = 'cover.jpg'

def extract_cover():

    try:
        tags = mutagen.mp3.Open()
        data = ""
        for i in tags:
            if i.startswith("APIC"):
                data = tags[i].data
                break
        if not data:
            return False
        else:
            with open(covers_dir + cover_name, "w") as cover:
                cover.write(data)
                return True
    except:
        logging.error('extract_cover: File \"%s\" not found in %s', local_file, covers_dir)
        return False

a = extract_cover()
print(a)
```

С помощью **print()** я пытался посмотреть, что возращает функция. Обложка никуда не сохраняется. Терминал выводит **False**. Не смог понять, где ошибка.

Пытался сделать так:

```
from mutagen.id3 import ID3

local_file = 'C:\\Users\\101ap\\Desktop\\music\\13.Numb.mp3'
covers_dir = 'C:\\Users\\101ap\\Desktop\\Player\\Cover'
cover_name = 'cover.jpg'

music = ID3(local_file)
data = music.getall("APIC")[0].data

with open(covers_dir + cover_name, "w") as cover:
    cover.write(str(data))
```

Появляется JPG-файл(конечно, не в той папке, где я хотел). Если пытаться его открыть, ничего кроме черного окна не появляется, позже появится сообщение, что такой формат не пооддерживается, какртинка ниже:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы зачем-то преобразовали байты картинки в текст и записали текстовый файл, но картинка очевидно не является текстовым файлом

Comment: `with open(covers_dir + cover_name, "wb") as cover: cover.write(data)`

Comment: Так просто искать APIC, прикольно. Я бы добавил проверку на FF D8  сигнатуру JPEG, вероятность повторения случайных APIC маленькая, но если будут ещё "сбойные" изображения, то лучше добавить.